# SAS: macro var in macro call

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a SAS macro

```
%macro corr(A, B, C);
....
%mend corr;
```

C is a macro variable.

```
% let c=
name
location
;
```

When I call macro corr, what should I do for c?

```
%corr(varA, varB, &varC.)?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%macro corr(A, B, C);
%put &C;
%mend corr;

%let c= name location;

%corr(varA, varB, &C.);
```

in the log, you can see "name location"